# More Android Fragment Backstack Confusion

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I've read so many SO posts and Android docs about this but for whatever reason it is not clicking with me - hoping somebody can set me straight.

I have a single activity where I am navigating through a sequence of fragments but I am not getting the backstack behavior I am expecting.  I have the following routine that I call to push the fragments:

```
public void pushFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag, boolean addToBackStack, boolean animate) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (animate)
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        else
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

        ft.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment, tag);

        if (addToBackStack)
            ft.addToBackStack(tag);

        ft.commit();
}
```

Fragments A, B and C are eventually displayed in the container one after the other through the following calls:

```
pushFragment(A, "A", true, false);
pushFragment(B, "B", true, true);   
pushFragment(C, "C", false, true);  // Don't add to backstack
pushFragment(B, "B", true, true);   // This happens after back clicked.
```

When hitting the back button while C is displayed, I get A as expected, at which point I would expect that C shouldn't be in any backstack transactions.  If at this point I attempt to move forward to B again, I see A immediately being replaced with C, then transitioning to B - which is confirmed by hitting back again which now displays C, not A.

Basically I expect (or want someway to get):
A -> B -> C -> BACK -> A -> B -> BACK -> A, etc...
but instead see:
A -> B -> C -> BACK -> A -> B -> BACK -> C

Apologies for what is almost certainly a duplicate post but was hoping somebody could re-explain such that it finally registers with me.

Thanks!!

Comment: I suspect the state of fragment A has "hide" visibility. Do you think that is possible? Perhaps you should post more code related to fragment A.

Comment: No, there are not any visibility changes.  I recreated w/ a very simple project consisting of three empty fragments w/ different bg colors and a shell activity.  The activity layout contains only the main_content container and a button, and the activity source has only the above pushFragment method and a button handler that issues the four pushFragment calls above in order, once per click.  Result is the same behavior where things seem to go sideways once a fragment is pushed that doesn't get added to the backstack (the third call) and then the back button is pressed.

Comment: Would still love to understand the native fragment backstack behavior, but have decided to implement my own stack that I could manipulate as I see fit - ultimately was very straight forward, wish I'd have done it from the get go...

Comment: Did you added code of "pushFragment(B, "B", true, true);" on the fourth line?  If so, I did not know that.

Comment: I edited the question to add the fourth line just to illustrate that that was the call that I would make after having hit the back button to go from A->B.  The problem seems to be introduced just prior to that when a fragment is pushed without addToBackstack.

Comment: I am still not sure. So is the fourth line considered the fix? It seems to me that the fourth code line would make it display fragment C.  If so, then the post is contradicting, and that might confuse readers.

Answer (score 0):

According to Android Developer Guide 
    Calling commit() does not perform the transaction immediately. Rather, it schedules it to run on the activity's UI thread (the "main" thread) as soon as the thread is able to do so. If necessary, however, you may call executePendingTransactions() from your UI thread to immediately execute transactions submitted by commit(). Doing so is usually not necessary unless the transaction is a dependency for jobs in other threads.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  In this case the transactions are all properly executing, and the backstack is updating as expected, confirmed by inspecting in debug.  It is the strange unwinding of the backstack when using the back button after issuing the replace transaction for a fragment without addToBackstack that I am struggling to understand.

Comment: Do you comit after replace transaction?

Comment: Yep - the last line in the pushFragment method is ft.commit();  There is no problem getting the replace transaction to execute, just not popping on back as expected.

Comment: I will suggest to have another transaction for "Testing Purpose" for Fragment C and just use your Helper class for fragment that you want to Back stack and see if that solve the problem